# RegEx that contains 'OR' pipelines matches pipelines in the input string

Tags: ruby, regex

As part of validation method, I need to ensure that an input string (called 'motif') does not contain certain characters (b, j, o ,u, x, z).

This is what I am currently using:

```
    if motif.match(/[b|j|o|u|x|z]/) #check whether the motif contains only amino acid residues and not other junk.
        dead("The motif query must only contain the following characters "ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY").)
    end
```

As the above script shows, if the motif contains these characters a method ('dead') is run,which stops the script.

The problem is that the above regex is that it also matches the pipeline `|` . This is a problem since the input would regularly contain pipelines.

e.g.

when the `motif = "RR|H..R"` , the script is stopped since the regex matches the pipeline.

I have tried escaping the pipeline with a `\` but this doesn't work...

Any help would be most appreciated.

Note: this is part of a ruby script.

Comment: help yourself: http://rubular.com/r/b50JzYnhJN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
motif.match(/[bjouxz]/)
```

**Since inside the character class pipe is treated literally i.e. a literal `|` not a regex OR.**

Following will also work (where pipe is treated as regex OR):

```
motif.match(/(b|j|o|u|x|z)/)
```

but its better/cleaner to use character class here.

Comment: No need of the parentheses inside the regex in your second example.

Comment: @sawa: That is correct parentheses isn't really required in 2nd example.

Comment: Note to Ismail M: Your mixed syntax is defeating the purpose of the character class `[]` notation. `/[abc]/` is shorthand for `/a|b|c/`. If you are using `[]`, then you should not be using `|`.

Comment: I think the regex should be case-insensitive as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a shorthand for `match`

```
motif[/[bjouxz]/]
```